# returning true outputs 1 but returning false outputs nothing

Tags: php, boolean

It's not very important but I was just curious to know the difference.

```
echo isA("A");  //outputs 1

echo isA("B");  //outputs nothing. why doesn't it output 0?
```

Anybody can shed somelight on this matter? It does seem to me as a double standard when you look at it from the point of view that "true" outputs as "1" but "false"does not output "0".

Again, no big deal but I think there must be a reason for PHP to be designed like that. Knowing that may give some more insight into this beautiful language.

A true value will manifest itself as a visible 1, but a false value won't. So, tell me what's the advantage of this method?

example function I referred above;

```
function isA($input){
    if ( $input == "A" ):
        return true;
    else:
        return false;
    endif;
}
```

Comment: Beautiful language? Disagree (but I'm PHP programmer as well) :P

Comment: @MuhammadAbrar: Beauty has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> A boolean TRUE value is converted to the string "1". Boolean FALSE is
> converted to "" (the empty string). This allows conversion back and
> forth between boolean and string values.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting

If you want to print a boolean for debugging you can use var_dump or print_r.

Answer (score 5):

Because when `false` is casted to string it becomes `''` -- empty string.

To see the difference use `var_dump();` instead of `echo`

```
var_dump((string) true);
var_dump((string) false);
```